# Is there a way to merge List<Stream<T>> to Stream<T> in ordered fashion on each stream in Dart?

Tags: dart

Assuming I have this:

```dart
final a = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]);
final b = Stream.fromIterable([3, 4]);
final c = Stream.fromIterable([5, 6]);
  
final streams = [a, b, c];
```

I want to merge all the streams in `streams`, which is of type `List<Stream<int>>`, into `Stream<int>`, but I also need to guarantee the order must be as below:

```
Stream Start |---1---3---5---2---4---6---| Stream End
```

> ℹ️ **Note**
>
> In this example, each stream exactly yields 2 items, but in the real code, these streams are not guaranteed to be fixed size.

Is there a way to do it? I couldn't find any kind of built-in method. I wonder if there's a way to do it in `rxdart`.

If there's no built-in or rxdart way to do it, you can just comment. At least I want to make sure I'm not missing out a ready-to-use implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen package:async (google-provided) with StreamGroup?  Does that do what you want?

Comment: [`StreamZip`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamZip-class.html) from `package:async` *almost* does what you want, except it will return a `Stream<List<int>>` with elements `[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]`.  It should be pretty straightforward to transform that into a `Stream<int>` if you need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamZip` + `expand` is the closest correct answer, which works even if the stream events are not perfectly interleaved automatically: `StreamZip(listOfStreams).expand((x)=>x)` gives a stream which waits for all streams to emit one event, then emits those events in the original stream order.

You haven't described what should happen if the streams have different lengths.

Another approach could be to iterate the streams one event at a time.

```dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:collection";

Stream<T> roundRobin<T>(Iterable<Stream<T>> streams) async* {
  var iterators = Queue<StreamIterator<T>>.from(streams.map(StreamIterator.new));
  while (iterators.isNotEmpty) {
    var first = iterators.removeFirst(); 
    try {
      if (await first.moveNext()) {
        iterators.add(first);
        yield first.current;
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      yield* Stream<T>.error(e, s);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MergeStream from [`rxdart`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/MergeStream-class.html).

```
    MergeStream([
      Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]),
      Stream.fromIterable([3, 4]),
      Stream.fromIterable([5, 6]),
    ]).listen(print);

// Output: 1 3 5 2 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Soliev's answer shows a simple way to do it with rxdart. For completeness's sake, here's a way to do it using just vanilla Dart:

```dart
final a = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]);
final b = Stream.fromIterable([3, 4]);
final c = Stream.fromIterable([5, 6]);

final controller = StreamController();
a.listen(controller.add);
b.listen(controller.add);
c.listen(controller.add);

controller.stream.listen(print);

// Output:
// 1
// 3
// 5
// 2
// 4
// 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first-party [`async`](https://pub.dev/packages/async) package from the dart team. Which has `StreamGroup.merge` function.

Here is a full example:

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';

void main() async {
  final a = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2]);
  final b = Stream.fromIterable([3, 4]);
  final c = Stream.fromIterable([5, 6]);
  final merged = StreamGroup.merge([a, b, c]);
  print(await merged.join(', ')); // 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6
}
```